# ¿Cuándo uso "acabar" vs. "terminar"? / When do I use "acabar" vs. "terminar"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, definiciones

I've seen both "acabar" and "terminar" used to mean "to finish" and "to end", for example:

- **"Cuando acabe el café, haga mas."** (*When you finish the coffee, make more*)
- **"La musica acabó y me senté en silencio por un momento."** (*The music ended and I sat in silence for a moment.*)
- **"La película terminó a las nueve."** (*The movie ended at 9.*)
- **"Terminamos el proyecto, y empezamos otro."** (*We finished the project and started another.*)

Are the two words totally interchangable for "to finish / to end", or are there certain situations where it is better to use one than the other? Is one of them more common in everyday speech?

Comment: Good question. Excepting for some very specific cases (e.g. when you finish a relationship you always say *terminar*), both words are quite interchangeable, but in practice one tends to be used more than the other depending on the case. I'll try to write an answer, but it is not easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe some sentences sound better with one or another verb, varying with the region, but the two verbs are quite common in speech and writing. You can use any of the two in almost any situation.

Let's see some of the meanings of both words, according to the RAE:

> **[acabar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0FQ0uWG)**
>
> De *cabo*.
>
> 1. tr. Poner o dar fin a algo. U. t. c. prnl.
> 2. tr. Apurar, consumir.
> 3. tr. Poner mucho esmero en la conclusión de una obra.
> 4. tr. matar.
> 5. intr. Rematar, terminar, finalizar. *La espada acaba en punta.*
> 6. intr. Poner fin, destruir, exterminar, aniquilar. *Los disgustos acabaron CON Pedro. Tú acabarás CON mi vida.*
> 7. intr. Haber ocurrido poco antes algo. *Acaba DE perder su caudal.*
> 8. intr. No lograr algo. U. con neg. *No acaba DE licenciarse.*

I have excluded the regionalisms and unused meanings.

> **[terminar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZYwREwl)**
>
> Del lat. *termināre*.
>
> 1. tr. Poner término a algo.
> 2. tr. acabar (‖ poner esmero en la conclusión de una obra).
> 3. intr. Dicho de una cosa: cesar (‖ interrumpirse o acabarse). U. t. c. prnl.
> 4. intr. Aniquilar o destruir enteramente algo o alguien. *Hay que terminar CON la injusticia y CON los explotadores.*
> 5. intr. Poner fin a las relaciones, especialmente amorosas, que se mantienen con otra persona. *Ha terminado CON su novio.*

Now let's see your examples. In all of them you can use any of the two verbs:

- **Cuando se acabe/termine el café, haga mas.** (1st of *acabar*, 3rd of *terminar*.)
- **La música acabó/terminó y me senté en silencio por un momento.** (1st of *acabar*, 3rd of *terminar*.)
- **La película acabó/terminó a las nueve.** (1st of *acabar*, 3rd of *terminar*.)
- **Acabamos/terminamos el proyecto, y empezamos otro.** (3rd of *acabar*, 2nd of *terminar*.)

Now let's match meanings:

- 1st of *acabar* is the same as *1st* of *terminar*. Seen in previous examples.
- 3rd of *acabar* is references in 2nd of *terminar*. Seen in previous examples.
- 3rd of *terminar* uses the verb *acabarse*.
- 4th of *acabar* can be expressed with the 4th of *terminar*. Example: *¡Acaba/termina con él!*
- 5th of *acabar* uses the verb *terminar*.
- 6th of *acabar* is the same as 4th of *terminar*.
- 8th of *acabar* can be expressed with the 1st of *terminar*. Example: *No termina de licenciarse.*

So we have the 7th meaning of *acabar*, which cannot be expressed with *terminar*: *termina de perder su caudal* does not make sense. And the 5th meaning of *terminar* cannot be expressed with *acabar*; as Gorpik said, if you say *Pedro acabó con su novia*, Pedro is sure to be on the news the next day (4th or 6th meanings of *acabar*), but you could say *Pedro acabó con la relación que mantenía con su novia*.

Answer (score 0):

They only scenarios where I can think on a difference is in the relationship context.

-Hace mucho no te veía, ¿cómo está tu novio? -**Terminamos** (we broke up).

On a slightly different context, a proper translation for "the relationship is over" is "el noviazgo acabó" where the synonym of terminar/acabar, applies again as others have answered.